# How to suppress Android Lint warning in Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, lint, suppress-warnings

I have the following annoying warning in my Android Lint report:

```
Gradle Dependency: Obsolete Gradle Dependency
A newer version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 than 20.+ is available: 21.0.0-rc1
```

The problem is I cannot use 21.0.0-rc1 because it does not work with my project. How can I suppress the warning?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can [disable lint warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) in Gradle. In this case:

```
android {

    lintOptions {
        disable 'GradleDependency'
    }

    ...
```

To disable the warning for a *specific* dependency, you can instead use the `noinspection` hint just above the line that causes the warning. Like this:

```
//noinspection GradleDependency
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
```

---

In Android Studio, you can turn off the "Obsolete Gradle Dependency" warning in Settings -> Project Settings -> Inspections.

[image]

Comment: This will only remove the warning in the IDE. When I run `./gradlew build` on command line, the warning is still present in the Lint report (build/outputs/lint-results.html)

Comment: @friederbluemle Added instructions for gradle :)

Comment: That works. Thanks. It would be nice if it was possible to **only** disable the check for a specific dependency, rather than globally. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: @friederbluemle Actually, yes! I didn't know this previously :) Edited answer again.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for!